# Creating an image for a Visual Basic command button?

Tags: image, vb6, paint, fireworks, commandbutton

I'm working on an application which was made in Visual Basic 6.0.  It was been made 8-10 years ago. There are different images used on the different command buttons. I have made a new image for a new button, but the image is not matched with the other images and I don't want to change all the old images.

I have used Fireworks 8.0, MS Office Picture Manager and MS Paint. However, I have failed to make the image the same as the others. I have attached a screen shot of the application. The new image is highlighted in a red rectangle. I want all the buttons to look the same. The new image looks a little blurry; also, the font is smooth, which it shouldn't be because the others aren't smooth.

[image: The toolbar from my application, with the new image highlighted.]

Comment: What type are the controls? Just standard VB6 CommandButtons or some custom control? Are the captions on the other command button controls part of the image, or are they set with the Caption property.

Comment: Yes the caption are a part of the image. I tried several fonts to match the font of other buttons in MS Paint but all in vain.

Comment: All are standard VB6 command and only images are used. Caption property is blank for all.

Comment: So there isn't any programming question here?  Just "help guess the mystery font" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced similar issue. I have tested the text of the image with some of the fonts and found that MS Sans Serif was matched with font of the other images. I wrote the text in MS-Paint then copied it and paste it with icon in Fireworks 8 and made the background transparent. It worked for me. You can try it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to try to make your images look like the previous images.

Try to find out which font was used. Turn off anti-aliasing in the image editor - that might be why the text looks smooth.

Perhaps you are drawing your image rather larger than the space available in the buttons, and then it is being shrunk to fit at runtime? That could make it look blurry. And have you used more colours than the other images? And more "subtle" colours, but the colours in the other images are quite brash.